# Database Design [item_details, ingredients]

Tags: database-design

I have the following table structure:

### item

id
name

### price

id
cost
item_id_fk

Lets say the item name is "burger with coke and french fries". These are 3 items treated as a single item in the item table. To factor out the item my idea is to create the following table:

### item_details

id
name
item_id_fk

### ingredient

id
name 
bundle_id_fk

So under the item_details I can add "Burger", "Coke", "French Fries". Then for each item_details I can add their respective ingredients.

Therefore is it considered a good design?

Comment: Will this be part of an ordering system?

Answer (score 1):

hm.. not really! there's a 1-to-1 relationship between item, price, and details.

I think you need something more like this ...

**MEAL Table**

```
id  meal_name
```

**MEAL_ITEMS Table**

```
id  meal_id  item_id
```

**ITEM Table**

```
id   name   price   description
```

**ITEM_INGREDIENTS Table**

```
id   item_id   ingredient_id
```

**INGREDIENTS Table**

```
id  name
```

Then another table, something like ...

The idea is ... MEALS can have many ITEMS ... ITEMS can have many INGREDIENTS.
With this MySQL can easily SUM() the prices of items in any given MEAL.

This query would show all ingredients used in meal 25:

```
SELECT ig.*
FROM `item_ingredients` as ii,
    `ingredients` as ig,
    `meal_items` as mi,
    'meals` as me
WHERE me.`id` = 25
  AND mi.`meal_id` = me.`id`
  AND ii.`item_id` = mi.`item_id`
  AND ig.`id` = ii.`ingredient_id`
```

This would show the sum of price of meal 25:

```
SELECT SUM(it.`price`)
FROM `items` as it,
    `meal_items` as mi,
    'meals` as me
WHERE me.`id` = 25
  AND mi.`meal_id` = me.`id`
  AND it.`id` = mi.`item_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to be part of an ordering system then you *need* to use table inheritance so that you can point the foreign key from an order line item to one table and not use the [polymorphic associations anti-pattern](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back).

```
Product

Good is a Product

Burger is a Good

French Fries is a Good

Pop is a Good

Bun is a Good...

Combo is a Product

Combo has many Products

Product belongs to CatalogItem

CatalogItem has a Price

Catalog has many CatalogItems

/* ingredients go here. similar to a combo except a combo can include services, and a BoM can include only goods */

BillOfMaterials belongs to a Good and has many Goods
```

You need to understand Database Table Inheritance.

We'll use Single Table Inheritance for simplicity.

Schema:

```
create table product_types (
  product_type_id int primary key,
  name text not null,
  parent_id int null references product_types(product_type_id)
);

create table products (
  product_id int primary key,
  type int not null references product_types(product_type_id),
  name text not null
);

create table combo_products (
  combo_id int references products(product_id),
  product_id int references products(product_id),
  quantity int not null default 1,
  primary key (combo_id, product_id)
);

create table catalogs (
  catalog_id int primary key,
  name text not null 
);

create table catalog_items (
  catalog_id int references catalogs(catalog_id),
  product_id int references products(product_id),
  price numeric(19,2) not null
);

create table bill_of_materials (
  good_id int references products(product_id),
  item_id int references products(product_id),
  quantity int not null default 1,

  primary key (good_id, item_id)
);
```

Usage:

```
insert into product_types values 
(1, 'Product', null),
(2, 'Good', 1),
(3, 'Combo', 1);

insert into products values
(1,2, 'Burger'),
(2,2, 'Fries'),
(3,2, 'Pop'),
(4,3, 'Combo 1'),
(5,2, 'Bun'),
(6,2, 'Patty'),
...;

insert into bill_of_materials values
(1, 5, 1), /*bun in burger*/
(1, 6, 1)  /*patty in burger*/
...;

insert into combo_products values 
(4, 1, 1), /*burger*/
(4, 2, 1), /*fries*/
(4, 3, 1); /*pop*/

insert to catalog values
(1, 'Default Catalog');

insert into catalog_items values
(1, 1, 4.99), /*burger*/
(1, 2, 2.49), /*fries*/
(1, 3, 1.99), /*pop*/
(1, 4, 7.99); /*combo1*/
```

Comment: I was thinking of this way: item [id, name], item_details [id, name, item_id_fk], ingredients [id, name, unit, quantity....]. In this manner 1 item has many item details. Then each item has many ingredients. For instance I create item [Burger with French Fries and Coke]. In my item details table I have the break down [Burger, French Fries, Coke]. Then I can specify the ingredients for each item details (except for coke).